# list object of struct is never assigned to and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#, list, struct, null, initialization

How should I initialize a List of a struct.
Struct can be initialized, but by just using my list here it says:
Folder is never assigned to and will always have its default value null

```
private struct directories
        {
            public List<string[]> Folder;
        }



directories d1 = new directories();
d1.Folder.Add(Directory.GetDirectories(path1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with structs is that their constructor is not guaranteed to run. E.g., when you create an array `var array = new directories[10];`. Therefore structs cannot have initializers and explicit parameterless constructors.

In this example I use lazy initialization to ensure the folder list to be initialized.

```
private struct directories
{
    private List<string[]> _folder;
    public List<string[]> Folder
    {
        get {
            if (_folder == null) {
                _folder = new List<string[]>();
            }
            return _folder;
        }
    }
}
```

---

But in this case I would simply use the existing [DirectoryInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) from the `System.IO` namespace. It does this and much more for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

```
DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
DirectoryInfo[] directories = rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Both, `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` have overloads allowing you to specify search patterns and whether you want to recurse subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but maybe I should have entered more code.
I am trying to get not just the directories of the rootdirectory. Also of the directories in the root and the directories in dierectories of root. Like all Subfolders of one rootdirectory.

Comment: So my Idea was to use two loops for this task:

for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < d1.Folder.Count; counter1++)
                        {
                            for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < d1.Folder[counter1].Length; counter2++)
                            {
                                d1.Folder.Add(Directory.GetDirectories(d1.Folder[counter1][counter2]));

Comment: `rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` will get you all the directories, including sub-directories and sub-sub-directories, etc. This is what I meant with "recurse subdirectories". See: [GetDirectories(String, SearchOption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetDirectories_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_).

Comment: so embarrassing that I missed it. THX worked out. here my code:

foreach (string folder1 in Directory.GetDirectories(path1, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        {

Comment: Hi now I noticed a problem after editing this. I got new errors for a network drive that an unexpected error occurred and after just throwing an exception my list wont be filled. Also when I took my C drive as path the recycle bin says unauthorized access and my list will be empty again.
Do you got an idea? Is it caused by the alldirectories option?

Comment: Still not knowing what to do. Sry